# Limiting value not machine-sized real number

Tags: plotting

How can I force an initial numeric calculation of plotting boundaries?

```
DP[L_, x_] := 2 π x (L - 20 Log10[x/10] - 45)
cp[Le_?NumericQ, Lc_?NumericQ] := N[10*(10^((Le - Lc)/20))]
Plot3D[DP[L, x], {L, 45, 85}, {x, cp[L, 65], cp[L, 45]}]
```

> Plot3D::plln: Limiting value cp[L,65] in {x,cp[L,65],cp[L,45]} is not
>   a machine-sized real number.

Comment: `{L, 45, 85}, {x, cp[L, 65], cp[L, 45]}` does not represent a rectangular region, which I believe that `Plot3D` requires.  You could try specifying a rectangular region that entirely enclosed the non-rectangular one that you have here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in my earlier comment, the plotting region passed to `Plot3D` is not a rectangular region.  Instead, it is

```
DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[cp[L, 65] < x < cp[L, 45] && 45 < L < 85, {L, x}], 
    {{45, 85}, {cp[45, 65], cp[85, 45]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {40, 0}]
```

[image]

To obtain a 3D plot over this region, call `Plot3D` with a rectangular region enclosing the actual region to be plotted, and use the `RegionFunction` option to specify that `DP` is to be evaluated only in the desired region.

```
Plot3D[DP[L, x], {L, 45, 85}, {x, cp[45, 65], cp[85, 45]}, AxesLabel -> {L, x, "DP"}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{L, x, z}, cp[L, 65] < x < cp[L, 45]], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: + just to be clear - I am very glad for the help. The RegionFunction is better, and nice to get to know.

Comment: My alternative was to set the function =0 when outside region I wanted: DP[L_, x_] /; x <= cp[L, 65] || x >= cp[L, 45] := 0 + Plot second function with fixed value zero to show the excluded area.